# Here Matrix Routing API gives unrealistic results for timetabled public transport route duration

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to use the Matrix Routing API to get public transport transit times between destinations. The request I'm making is:

https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable;traffic:enabled&destination0=40.7206,-74.04651&start0=40.89908,-73.77962&departure=2015-07-16T09:00:01

which yields a route with `{u'BaseTime': 3140.0, u'Distance': 47036.0}`

Making the request for same locations via the Routing API:
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=40.89908,-73.77962&waypoint1=40.7206,-74.04651&combineChange=false&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable;traffic:enabled&departure=2015-07-16T09:00:01&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

gives: `{u'baseTime': 6932, u'distance': 37585,}`

The latter is more in line with what the here.com site provides:
https://www.here.com/directions/publicTransport/N40.7206-,-W74.04651:40.7206,-74.04651/N40.89908-,-W73.77962:40.89908,-73.77962?map=40.81592,-73.91308,11,grey&leave=1437030000000

How can I get the matrix API to respond with reasonable time estimates for public transport?

If switch the `mode` in the matrix request to `car` I also get 3140 as basetime. Setting it to `publicTransport` gives a whopping 20742 seconds.

Is it a coincidence that the the matrix API response for `car` and `publicTransportTimeTable` modes is identical? Or is this a hint that something is messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably out of luck - according to the [Developer's Guide](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/matrix-routing/topics/request-type-transport-mode.html) only two transport modes are supported in the **Matrix Routing API 6.2** :

- `car`    Route calculation for cars.
- `truck`  Route calculation for trucks. This mode will consider truck
  limitations on links and will use different speed assumptions when
  calculating the route.

The Public transport mode is only available in the  [**Routing API**](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/examples-public-transport.html) **7.2**

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly it does support `pedestrian` even though it's not listed in the docs as a valid `mode` value.  The `publicTransport` mode returns  the same duration as `pedestrian` and `publicTransportTimeTable` the same as the `car` mode. Would be nice if they gave an error message if an unsupported mode is used instead of giving confusing results.